Finding the projective cover of a quotient of ring matrices.
Let $R$ be the ring $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $I= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ a left ideal of $R$. I would like to compute the projective $R$ left cover of $R/J$. First and foremost, I want to consider the chance of $R/I$ to be a left projective $R$ module. I have a hunch that this will not be the case since I cannot find any other left $R$ ideal of $R$ (let's say $I^{\ast}$)such that $R= I^{\ast} \oplus I $. I mean if we pick up the more likely to be summand $I^{\ast}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ it turns out that $I^{\ast}$ of $R$ is not a left ideal of $R$.I also considered to use the first isomorphism Theorem to "reduce" $R/I$ into a more friendly quotient of rings but the attempts were not fruitful. I would really like to provide more attempts to find a solution but I'm really strugling getting to grips with this problem. Thanks.

It turns out that $I$ is a projective left $R$-module, but $R/I$ isn't.

Denote ($*$ stands for an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$).
$$
J_1=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}*&0\\ 0&0\end{array}\right)\},
$$
$$
J_2=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&*\\ 0&*\end{array}\right)\},
$$
$$
M_1=\{\left(\begin{array}{c}*\\ 0\end{array}\right)\},
$$
$$
M_2=\{\left(\begin{array}{c}*\\ *\end{array}\right)\}.
$$

Here $J_1$ and $J_2$ are both left ideals of $R$. Clearly
$R=J_1\oplus J_2$, so they are both projective left $R$-modules.
$M_2$ is a left $R$-module w.r.t. matrix multiplication, and $M_1$ is its only non-trivial submodule.
As left $R$-modules, $M_1\simeq J_1$ and $M_2\simeq J_2$, so both $M_1$ and $M_2 $ are projective.
As left $R$-modules $I\simeq M_1\oplus M_1$, and hence projective as a direct sum of projective left $R$-modules.


About the actual question. It sure looks like $R/I\simeq M_2/M_1$, and $M_1$ is a superfluous submodule of $M_2$. Doesn't it follow that $M_2$ is a projective cover of $M_2/M_1$, and hence of $R/I$?

@Jyrki_Lahtonen Hi Jirky, thank a lot!! Yes it seems like $M_{2}$ as you described it a projective cover of the quotient $M_{2} / M_{1}$.  However, I don't see how $I \cong M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$? I mean, on the one hand it is easy to see that $M_{1} + M_{2} \cong I_{2}$. On the other hand I'm not able to see that $M_{1} \cap M_{2} = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Maybe there is something I'm missing out.

@Cos Read carefully! $I\simeq M_1\oplus M_1$. An outer direct sum of two copies of $M_1$. So $M_1\times M_1$ as a set, and componentwise module action.

Similarly $R\simeq M_1\oplus M_2$, where $M_1$ is identified with $J_1$ and $M_2$ with $J_2$. If, instead, we had the full matrix ring $S$, then $S\simeq M_2\oplus M_2$ (one column at a time), but $M_1$ would not be an $S$-module at all.

@Jyrki_Lahtonen Kiitos, Jyrki. And yes I might still ask another similar question about the Injectiviness of $M_{2}$. I just want to mull over about it a little bit more. I'm trying with an equivalence of Baer's criterion now I know the ideals of $R$. Still a lot of computing.
